# An auxiliary problem while constructing the system of Jordan sets on a plane

Tags: real-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, measure-theory

Let $\mathfrak{S}$ be a system of rectangles in $R^2$ of the form $[a,b]\times [c,d]$
where $a,b,c, d \in R$, $a<b$, $c<d$.
Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a system of simple sets based on $\mathfrak{S}$.
The set $X$ is simple if it may be represented as a union of the sets from $\mathfrak{S}$.
Given an arbitrary bounded set $M \subset R^2$ and its boundary is
embedded into a simple set $X$: $\partial M \subset X$.
Can we assert, that the closure of $M \setminus X$ is a simple set ?